# Perl set locale to POSIX but show C?

Tags: perl, posix, locale

Using `POSIX` module, I can get current locale value in `perl`:

```
$ LC_ALL=vi_VN.utf8 perl -MPOSIX=setlocale,locale_h,LC_ALL -le 'print setlocale(LC_ALL)'
LC_CTYPE=vi_VN.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=vi_VN.utf8;LC_COLLATE=vi_VN.utf8;
LC_MONETARY=vi_VN.utf8;LC_MESSAGES=vi_VN.utf8;LC_PAPER=vi_VN.utf8;LC_NAME=vi_VN.utf8;
LC_ADDRESS=vi_VN.utf8;LC_TELEPHONE=vi_VN.utf8;LC_MEASUREMENT=vi_VN.utf8;
LC_IDENTIFICATION=vi_VN.utf8
```

But if I set locale to `POSIX`, `perl` print `C` instead of `POSIX`:

```
$ LC_ALL=POSIX perl -MPOSIX=setlocale,locale_h,LC_ALL -le 'print setlocale(LC_ALL)'
C
```

Is this default behavior of `perl` or I have made some mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `POSIX` locale is an alias for the `C` locale. Presumably on your system, `setlocale(..., "POSIX")` sets the locale to `C`, and you get that name back instead of the one you passed in.

Comment: Is there any document about this? I read `perldoc perllocale` but did not see this information.

Comment: @Gnouc [The POSIX standard.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html)